# Mongo import, attempting to insert document exceeds 16mb limit

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to import a 384.8mb json file into Mongo, after running for about two minutes an error occurs preventing the import.

```
warning: attempting to insert document with size 483.6 MB (exceeds 16.0 MB limit)
```

The documentation on the Mongo site says that the bson has a size limit of 16mb (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/).

What is the recommended approach for importing a file of this size?

Below is a non-verbose output from my console

```
$  mongoimport -d myprovider -c collection --file data/myprovider_6am.json
2015-05-06T16:47:29.353-0700  connected to: localhost
2015-05-06T16:47:32.345-0700  [###############.........] myprovider.collection  256.0 MB/384.8 MB (66.5%)
2015-05-06T16:47:35.344-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:47:38.345-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:47:41.345-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:47:44.343-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:47:47.342-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:47:54.053-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:47:56.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:47:59.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:02.342-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:05.343-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:08.343-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:11.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:14.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:17.343-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:20.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:23.346-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:26.342-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:29.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:37.839-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:38.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:41.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:44.344-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:47.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:50.343-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:53.344-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:56.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:48:57.837-0700  warning: attempting to insert document with size 483.6 MB (exceeds 16.0 MB limit)
2015-05-06T16:48:59.341-0700  [########################] myprovider.collection  384.8 MB/384.8 MB (100.0%)
2015-05-06T16:49:00.306-0700  error inserting documents: write tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: broken pipe
2015-05-06T16:49:00.306-0700  imported 0 documents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**GridFS**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/#gridfs) is what you are looking for.

If you have document whose size is beyond `16mb` can be stored in mongo's `gridfs`, which stores chunks of file instead of storing as a single document.

Which has many benefits other than just storing document greater than 16mb size like accessing without loading the entire file into memory.

You should also read [When should I use GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-when-to-use-gridfs)?